# Source for an ideal Shidduch based on proximity

Tags: marriage, shidduchim-dating

A Rebbi of mine in yeshiva said in the name of [Rav Ruderman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Yitzchok_Ruderman) z"tl who referred to a Chazal that a person should ideally try to marry someone from the "same מבוי (street), if not then the same שכונה (neighbourhood), and if not then the same עיר (city)," explaining that the fewer differences there are, the easier the adjustment which is required for marriage.

My question is where this Chazal is located? (My Rebbi wasn't sure, although I was wondering if it's [Yalkut Shimoni 391:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.391.14?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah&lang=bi))

Comment: Not the exact phrasing, but the Midrash Mishle ([ch. 5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14102&st=&pgnum=51)) comments on "יהי מקורך ברוך ושמח מאשת נעורך" (Prov. 5:18): "From here they said: Lucky is the man whose wife is from his town, his Torah [study] is from his town and his livelihood is from his town."

Comment: Looks like I accidentally linked (above) to a page later.